# Resize DIV but maintain aspect ratio when window is resized

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV element in my page, that I want to resize when the window is resized, but maintain a square aspect ratio.  I want to set the width to be 50% of the browser width, and the height to be equal to the width.  How can I do this?

If the solution requires Javascript that's fine but I'd prefer not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `width:50%` in css and `window.onresize` event for resize. Have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/536UJ/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can make one property (height) equal to other property (width) in CSS... well, at least in CSS 2.

But you of course can do this in JavaScript.

```
<div id = "myDiv"></div>
<script>
    document.onresize = function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');      // the element
        var size = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 2) + 'px'; // 50% window width

        element.style.width = size;  // set the width
        element.style.height = size; // set the height
    };
</script>
```

Note that the `window.innerWidth` property is not present in IE. There, you'll have to use `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.

Comment: I admit, I tested this only on Opera. What browser are you using, to help me debug?

Comment: All except Opera lol... I think it's because you referenced the div name in the last two lines instead of the variable name.  Otherwise it would have worked

Comment: Yeah, that really could be the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width to be 50% of the window in css;
you just need to adjust the height-

```
window.onresize=function(){
  var who= document.getElementById('divtoresize');
  who.style.height=who.offsetWidth+'px';
}
```